# Smart merging of columns of multiple choices with pandas' data frames

Tags: python, pandas

The results of an opinion pool are stored in CSV format in which questions with multiple answers are coded with 0 and 1. For example, if the question "which is your favorite color?" is asked to 100 people, and possible answers are limited to red, blue, green, a result such as

```
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
votes = [33, 57, 10]
```

will be stored by means of three columns: one for 'red' answer containing 33 1's and 67 0's, one for 'blue' containing 57 1's and 43 0's, and one for 'green' containing 10 1's and 90 0's.

I would like to transform my data frame so that these three colums are merged into a unique column containing occurences of 'red', 'blue' and 'green'.

Here is a simplified example of my problem:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

actual_pool = {'foo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
               'red': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               'blue': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               'green': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
               'bar': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']}

actual_df = DataFrame(actual_pool,columns= ['foo', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'bar'])

expected_pool = {'foo': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
                 'colors': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'],
                 'bar': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']}

expected_df = DataFrame(expected_pool,columns= ['foo', 'colors', 'bar'])

print(actual_df)
print(expected_df)
```

The question is *How can I get expected_df from actual_df with pandas?*.

EDIT 1: add columns 'foo' and 'bar' because I am interested in merging a subsets of columns of data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.idmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) to get column name with max value :

```
actual_pool = {'red': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               'blue': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               'green': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]}

actual_df = DataFrame(actual_pool,columns= ['red', 'blue', 'green'])

actual_df['colors'] = actual_df.idxmax(axis=1)

print(actual_df)
```

Output:

```
  red  blue  green   colors                                                                                                            
0    1     0      0    red                                                                                                            
1    0     1      0   blue                                                                                                            
2    0     0      1  green                                                                                                            
3    1     0      0    red                                                                                                            
4    0     0      1  green                                                                                                            
5    1     0      0    red                                                                                                            
6    0     1      0   blue                                                                                                            
7    0     1      0   blue
```

**If you have extra columns**

```
from pandas import DataFrame

actual_pool = {'red': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               'blue': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
               'green': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                'pink': [12,0,11,2,0,90,0,12]
}

actual_df = DataFrame(actual_pool,columns= ['red', 'blue', 'green'])

actual_df['colors'] = actual_df[['red','blue','green']].idxmax(axis=1)

print(actual_df)
```

Comment: Wow, I am impressed! Does this solution can be applied to a subset of contiguous columns in a DataFrame?

Comment: It takes into account all the numeric columns in your data and returns the name of the column with max value.

Comment: I fear my example is too simple. I will edit it to take this dimension of the problem into account.

Comment: It can be applied even if you have large dataset, just use the columns from which you want to find max.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
small_df = actual_df[['red', 'blue', 'green']]
small_df.eq(1) @ small_df.columns
```

will give output

```
0      red
1     blue
2    green
3      red
4    green
5      red
6     blue
7     blue
dtype: object
```